# Number of Leaves in a Binary Tree Python

Tags: python, binary-tree

I have a data structure that looks like this Q = (A,(B,C)). Len(Q) obviously equals 2. But I only care about the leaves (A, B, C). What's a function I can use that will return function(Q) = 3?

Comment: `A` is not a leaf... Are you looking for the number of nodes in the tree ?

Comment: What's the format of your tree? I would also argue that A is not a leaf.

Comment: @alfasin Unless `A` is leaf, then we have something like level order traversal. Leaf nodes will be `len(Q[-1]) if Q else 0`

Comment: @ferhatelmas leaves can be on different levels ;)

Comment: @alfasin right, not that easy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive function:

```
def rec_len(thing):
    if isinstance(thing, basestring):
        return 1
    try: 
        return sum(rec_len(x) for x in thing)
    except TypeError:
        return 1
```

Note that you have to guard against things that are 'string-like' because otherwise you'll end up counting the letters of your leaf nodes.

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_nodes(tree):
    if not tree:
        return 0
    elif type(tree) == str:
        return 1
    else:
        return count_nodes(tree[0]) + count_nodes(tree[1:])


tree = ('a', ('b', ('d', 'e'), 'c', ('f', 'g')))
print count_nodes(tree) # prints 7
```

That said, if what you want is really the leaves (in your example: `(B,C)`), you can turn it into a string, use regex, and revert:

```
import re

tree = ('a', ('b', ('d', 'e'), 'c', ('f', 'g')))
res = re.findall(r'\([^(]+?\)', str(tree))
res = map(eval, res)
print res # [('d', 'e'), ('f', 'g')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def flatten(container):
    for i in container:
        if isinstance(i, list) or isinstance(i, tuple):
            for j in flatten(i):
               yield j
        else:
            yield i

sum(1 for _ in flatten(Q))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def flatten(q):
    if not q:
        return 0
    if isinstance(q, tuple):
        if not isinstance(q[0], tuple):
            return 1+flatten(q[1:])
        else:
            return flatten(q[0]) + flatten(q[1:])
    else:
        return 1
```